# How to move User info block(user login block) from its original postion to the menu top bar in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

> Blockquote
>   i am using prestashop version 1.6.0.10,i want to move userlogin(User info block module) to menu top bar(top horizonatl menu module) 
>   any idea please help?
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

You should go to Backoffice menu: Modules -> Modules Position. Look for Transplant Hook option in the upper right of the screen. That way you can hook the module to specific hook you want.

NOTE: module must implement that hook to allows you to transplant it to that hook. If not, you should implement it modifying source code.

Good luck.